# JavaScript mapping and filtering a basic array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

Having this array

```
[ { name: 'foo', gender: 'm' }, { name: 'bar', gender: 'f' }, { name: 'baz', gender: 'f' }  ]
```

How is it (maybe in a one-liner) possible to transform it into:

```
[ { gender: 'f', names: [ { name: 'bar' }, { name: 'baz' } ] } ]
```

Filtered by gender
Vanilla JS, ES6 and/or ES7.

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: (FWIW, `map` wouldn't really apply here. `filter` would in some solutions, not in others.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could filter by `gender` and map objects with `name`.

```js
var array = [{ name: 'foo', gender: 'm' }, { name: 'bar', gender: 'f' }, { name: 'baz', gender: 'f' }],
    object = { gender: 'f', names: array
        .filter(({ gender }) => gender === 'f')
        .map(({ name }) => ({ name }))
    };

console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#reduce` to group your data based on `gender` in an object accumulator. Then get all the values from this object using `Object.values()`.

```js
const data = [ { name: 'foo', gender: 'm' }, { name: 'bar', gender: 'f' }, { name: 'baz', gender: 'f' }  ],
      group = Object.values(data.reduce((r, {name, gender}) => {
        r[gender] = r[gender] || {gender, names : []};
        r[gender].names.push({name});
        return r;
      },{}));
console.log(group);
```